# Products displayed with $0.0, with no name and No image

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, products-view

I created a extension for displaying `Most viewed products` in home page. I am able to see the products but there is no name or image and `the price is displayed as $0.0`. I am not able to figure out the reason for `why the products are displayed in this way`.

Please help me

[image]

Code in Block file:

```
parent::__construct();
        $storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')  
            ->addOrderedQty()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'))
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
            ->addViewsCount();

        if(Mage::getStoreConfig('catalogextensions/config3/max_product'))
        {
            $products->setPageSize(Mage::getStoreConfig('catalogextensions/config3/max_product'));
        }


        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);
        Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($products);

        $this->_productCollection = $products;
        //var_dump($products);
```

//die();
            return $this->_productCollection;

Code in phtml file:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalogextensions/mostviewed_home_list')->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: please put your code?

Comment: Wild guess: you did not specify the attributes to load with the product collection.

Comment: I have added the code in the question..

Answer (score 0):

Using my psychic powers I see that you did retrieve the collection like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')->addViewsCount()....;
```

and you forgot to add any attributes to the collection.
You should do something like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')->addViewsCount()
//   ...other filters here
        ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addUrlRewrite();
```

**[Edit]**
Ah...my psychic powers are failing me. You did add them. But you added the `addViewsCount` at the end. That method resets the select. You need to add the attributes after calling `addViewsCount`

Comment: your psychic power is so strength :-) File: app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php:365 "$this->getSelect()->reset()"